# What is the necessary code to retrieve the height of a histogram bar in Bokeh?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, visualization, bokeh

Objective: Obtain the value of the y-axis in the hover/tooltip provided by Bokeh (python).

Currently, I have tried @y and @height both give me '???' value within the hover/tooltip. I have followed, closely, much of the [documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/styling.html) surrounding the hover/tooltip in Bokeh, but to no avail.

[image]

Any advice would be helpful...

Below is the code I am using:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg import autompg as df

from numpy import histogram, linspace

from bokeh.models import HoverTool

# Information contained within the hoover

hist, edges = histogram(data['Age'], density=False, bins=10)

hover = HoverTool( tooltips="""
    <div style ="border-style: solid;border-width: 15px;border-color: gray;background-color:gray;padding:0">         
        <div>
            <span style="font-size: 12px; color: white;font-family:century gothic;">'@y'</span>
            <span style="font-size: 12px; color: white;font-family:century gothic;"> Observations</span>
        </div>
    </div style>

    """
)


p = figure(plot_height=300,tools=[hover])
p.quad(top=hist, bottom=0, left=edges[:-1], right=edges[1:],line_color="white", line_width=1,color='gray',fill_alpha=.50)

p.title="Distribution of Age"

p.title_text_font = "Century Gothic"
p.title_text_font_style='normal'
p.title_location='above'
p.title_text_align= 'center'
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font = "Century Gothic"
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_color = 'black'
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_style='normal'
p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font = "Century Gothic"
p.yaxis.axis_label_text_color = 'black'
p.yaxis.axis_label_text_font_style = "normal"
p.xaxis.axis_label_standoff = 10
p.yaxis.axis_label_standoff = 10

# Tufte style
p.background_fill_color = None

p.border_fill_color = None
p.min_border_left = 80

p.xaxis.major_tick_line_color = None  # turn off x-axis major ticks
p.xaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None  # turn off x-axis minor ticks

p.yaxis.major_tick_line_color = None  # turn off y-axis major ticks
p.yaxis.minor_tick_line_color = None  # turn off y-axis minor ticks

p.ygrid.grid_line_color = "gray"
p.ygrid.grid_line_alpha = 0.25
p.ygrid.grid_line_width = 1
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None

p.yaxis.axis_line_color = None
p.xaxis.axis_line_color = None

# Remove outline of graph
p.outline_line_color = None

# Remove Bokeh logo
#p.toolbar.logo = None
p.toolbar_location = None
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Age'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Count'

show(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

For `@xxx` to work, you need to pass a data source to the glyph method. I'm not sure whether `$xxx` should work without a data source or if it's a peculiarity of the `quad` glyph.

Here's how you can do it:

```
# After you bin your data
h_data = pd.DataFrame({'Count': hist, 'Bin': edges[1:]})  # Adjust the edges selection as desired

# HoverTool definition
hover = HoverTool( tooltips="""
<div style ="border-style: solid;border-width: 15px;border-color: gray;background-color:gray;padding:0">         
    <div>
        <span style="font-size: 12px; color: white;font-family:century gothic;">@Count</span>
        <span style="font-size: 12px; color: white;font-family:century gothic;"> Observations</span>
    </div>
</div style>
""")

# Instead of the quad call
p.vbar(x='Bin', width=2.75, top='Count', bottom=0, line_color='white', line_width=1, color='gray', fill_alpha=0.50, source=h_data)
```

You can also do it with a low-level `quad` call but you need to create a data source with 3 columns (left and right edges, bottom can still be a constant 0). `vbar` is more explicit though and you could even improve the 'Bin' column to represent the interval instead of the right (or left edge).

Note there were a few typos (I think or possibly you use an older version of bokeh) regarding `p.title_text_font_style` which should be `p.title.text_font_style` and one or two others in the same vein.